# Arranging component vertically on a jpanel

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I have been trying to use any of the layout manager class to arrange GUI elements vertically but all to no avail.I actually want number of courses serve as input to be able to create the number of jtextfield lined vertically and there would still be spaces to lay textboxes for the other three columns.. Thanks, Here is the code below:

```
new GPA_Calculator().setVisible(false);
                  String a = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the number of courses");
                  Integer b = Integer.parseInt(a);
                  final int FRAME_WIDTH = 400;
                  final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 400;
                  JFrame aFrame = new JFrame("GPA Calculator");
                  aFrame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
                  aFrame.setVisible(true);
                  aFrame.setResizable(false);
                  aFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                  JPanel panel = new JPanel ();
                  aFrame.add(panel);
                  GridLayout grid = new GridLayout (b,4);
                  panel.setLayout(grid);  
                  for (int counter = 0; counter < b; counter++)
                  {
                  JTextField textfield = new JTextField(5);
                  panel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                  panel.add(textfield);
```

Comment: If I understand the question right. You can use GridBagLayout with GridBagConstraints for these layouts, or use "b" amount of JPanels with GridLayout(0,1) within a container panel which has GridLayout(4,0)

Comment: You probably want to use [Box.createVerticalBox()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Box.html#createVerticalBox--) instead of a JPanel.  It will already have a layout manager installed, and you won't need to keep track of the number of components you add.

Comment: The Box class was able to solve the problem to an extent. However, I am trying to size up the JTextField to the appropraite size because it expands to suite the entire frame. Any ideas to how to work around that..Thanks

Comment: I dont really get the use of GridBagLayout..A few detailed explanation or lines of code would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: `A few detailed explanation or lines of code would be appreciated` - Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for explanations and working examples.